# Как сохранить состояние WebView в MainActivity?

Tags: android, webview

Пишу простой браузер. Не могу разобраться с сохранением состояния `WebView` в `MainActivity`. При первой загрузке приложения открывается стартовая страница google.com. Предположим, я пишу что-то в поисковой строке. Как сохранить состояние `WebView`, чтобы текст, написанный в поисковой строке, не пропадал после смены ориентации экрана?
Код `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.webView)
    WebView webView;

    @Inject
    UrlPreferences prefs;

    MyWebViewClient webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        App.INSTANCE.getAppComponent().inject(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initButterKnife();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
        } else {
            webView.loadUrl(prefs.getUrl());
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        prefs.setUrl(webView.getUrl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добавить запрет на перезагрузку данных активности:

```
<activity ...
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">
```

Либо второй вариант - восстанавливать состояние из `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    webView.saveState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
}
```

и в `onCreate()` восстанавливаем ее:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.blah);
   WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
   if (savedInstanceState != null)
      webview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
   else
      webview.loadUrl(URLData)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно в манифесте в теге <Activity...> прописать android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"?

Comment: @KurtcaBain, это тоже один из вариантов :)

Comment: Отлично, благодарю ещё раз)