# Сохранение истории webview android

Tags: java, android, swift, kotlin, webview

Как можно сохранить WebBackForwardList? И инициализировать им вебвью при запуске приложения. Больше всего интересует второй этап. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Там есть механизм сохранения состояния, но он не работает при нормальном закрытии активности: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1107645/11515. Как вариант посмотрите под каким ключом этот лист сохраняется в бандл, сам лист сохраните в файл, при старте восстановите из файла, положите в бандл и отдайте в вебвью

Comment: Примерно так и сделал.